# Meaning of "Mr Right's first name is Always"

Tags: quotes

What does this quote mean?

> When I eventually met Mr. Right I had no idea that his first name was Always.
>
> — Rita Rudner

Answer (score 52):

It's a joke. It's common to talk about "Mr. Right" ... meaning, the ideal man for marriage.

On the other hand, people who are "full of themselves", who talk too much, who always think they know best ... they have an "I'm always right" attitude.

Note that if your name was "Something Right" (say, John Right, or Joe Right) ... it's a bit like that: first name is "Always" ... "Mr. Always Right"

So, it's a joke.

Comment: Note also that Rita Rudner is a well-known professional stand-up comedian.  So... "it's a joke".

Comment: And for those who are not patient enough to wait for Mr. Right, there is always Mr. Right Now. ;)

Comment: It's tough because this relies on two pop culture/colloquial expressions in order to make the joke. But like they say, if you have to [explain the joke, there is no joke](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Dontexplainthejoke).

Comment: Just FYI if you're a non-English speaker: they are both extremely common in English, so it's very straightforward. Cheers!

Comment: I got fifty points for this!

Answer (score 7):

When Rita first met the man, she thought he was perfect ("Mr. Right"). Later she realized that he thought so too. He's a know-it-all, he *thinks* he is always right.

Comment: And how is this answer any different than the already existing answer?  It's the exact same explanation except with a hell of a lot less detail...

Comment: I found this explanation clearer.